# Study of superconductivity from organic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, conductivity

What advancements have been made in understanding and applying organic superconductor materials?

Although traditionally superconductivity has been studied in inorganic materials, are there any organic compounds showing superconducting properties?

As far as I know, superconductivity is a state where materials conduct electricity without resistance, observed in inorganic materials at extremely low temperatures.

Comment: There's [a very nice Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_superconductor) you can start from.

Comment: There certainly are organic superconductors, but they are not very practical in use. Even things like cuprates, are still pretty early in introduction to practical usage.

Answer (score 1):

As you can find on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_superconductor), many organic materials were found to show superconducting properties. These organic superconductors are intriguing because they offer the possibility of understanding superconductivity in a different structural and electronic context compared to inorganic superconductors. They might also lead to the discovery of materials that become superconducting at higher, more practical temperatures. Additionally, the flexibility and tunability of organic chemistry mean we can design and modify these compounds more easily, potentially optimizing their superconducting properties.